# How to make a Global function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get this function to be know by all controllers but i don't know how to put a function as a global.

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var SoundMute = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    }

    func CheckMusicMute() {
        if InGameMusicOnOff == true {
            SoundMute.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "SilverCircle.png")!     
        }
        if InGameMusicOnOff == false {
            SoundMute.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "RedCircle.png")!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method and variable names should start with a lower case letter.  You shouldn't compare directly against boolean literals (you can just write `if InGameMusicOnOff`), and you should investigate the `else` keyword.  Barring multithreading or `InGameMusicOnOff` being some sort of computed value based on `SoundMute`'s `texture` property (which looks impossibly in this context), your two conditions are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom class with the method you need like this:

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
    func CheckMusicMute() {
        if InGameMusicOnOff == true {
            SoundMute.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "SilverCircle.png")!
        }
        if InGameMusicOnOff == false {
            SoundMute.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "RedCircle.png")!
        }
    }
}
```

Then make `GameScene` extend `MyScene`:

```
class GameScene: MyScene
```